# android Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.media.video.frc.support"

Tags: java, android

Problems encountered when running the project to video save
Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.media.video.frc.support"

[image]

Comment: Are you using cast for youtube?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.